# Issue with XSL Display since Chrome 123 Update

Tags: asp.net, xml, google-chrome, xslt, frame

Since the recent update to Chrome version 123, I've been facing an issue with displaying XSL (XSLT) within iframes on my web application. Normally, the XSL content is loaded into an iframe using XSLT transformation, but since this update, the iframe remains empty, and the XSL doesn't display at all.

Here my code behind aspx.vb (when I transform and load the xml).

```
Private Sub bindData()
' Code to retrieve data and generate XML content for transformation
' ...

' Code to generate XSLT interface and XSL content
' ...

' Code to clean XML for construction
' ...

' XML header preparation
' ...

' Construction of XML content with XSL
' ...

' Sending response with XML content
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
Response.Write(sXMLlistEdit)
```

End Sub

I also use a function to clean XML before construction, but I don't believe this is relevant to the current issue.

Here the header of my .xsl :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dt="http://xsltsl.org/date-time">
<xsl:include href="../string.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="../date-time.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="url_site"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/url_site" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="VersionJs"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/VersionJs" /></xsl:variable>  
<html>
```

I have also attempted to force the use of the TLS 1.2 protocol in my ASP.NET application by adding the above code to the Application_Start method in my Global.asax.vb file, but it did not resolve the issue.

I've already checked the validity of the XSL, the accessibility of the XSL URL, and inspected errors in the browser console, but I couldn't find a solution. I also tried testing with simplified XSL, but the problem persists.

Here my header of my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://localhost/front/front/dossier_front_liste_type_date_front.xsl?v=13.0.2412.0.17498"?>
<NewDataSet>
```

Also, I don't see anything in the network tab; it does load the files string.xsl and date-time.xsl. However, I notice in the Chrome console, it doesn't load all the files... it's as if it stops.

Furthermore, it's worth mentioning that everything works perfectly fine locally, but the issue arises only when accessing the application from a server.
This addition highlights the difference in behavior between the local environment and the server environment, which could provide valuable insights into the root cause of the problem....

Thank you.

Comment: Are no error or warning messages at all in the console?

Comment: And can you test on your own whether using ASP.NET to generate the XML/XSLT is part of the problem or whether Chrome also fails with static XML/XSLT files?

Comment: @MartinHonnen here are no errors or warnings in the console. When I check the response of my .xsl, everything seems correct. The only difference between my localhost and my website is that my local environment loads more files. It appears that the website doesn't load properly, or something similar to that.

Comment: Edge also has the 123 release, I think, so you could check there too and if the issue exists, file it on Microsoft Edge and/or Google Chrome. I am not sure what we on Stackoverflow can do about it